# Appending text to FTP instead of overwriting

Tags: c#, text, ftp, append

I'm trying to ***append*** a line of text to a txt file online, but the code I've tried is replacing all the txt in the file as opposed to adding a new line, even after adding `Enviorment.Newline`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
  private void submithsbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

        string peak = peakvaluelbl.Text;
        string dir = @"ftp://example.com/file.txt";
        string name = nametbox.Text;

       client.UploadString(dir, name + " recived a peak score of: " + peak + Environment.NewLine);        
    }
```

Does anyone know how I might be able to achieve the result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the high level webClient Class is too abstract for what you you want to do.

this [ftpWebRequest example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.getrequeststream(v=vs.110).aspx)  achieve what you wish to do.

```cs
private static void AppendString(Uri target,byte[] data) {
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(target);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.AppendFile;
    request.ContentLength = data.length;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
    response.Close();
}
```

Comment: Wow, it took me a bit of fiddling around, but this actually ended up working. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

There is an overloaded method WebClient UploadString which takes three arguments and the second one being to specify the method.

```
client.UploadString(url,"APPE",data);
```

Check from the List of FTP commands [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_commands).

Comment: I was using this, but IIRC this was replacing the contents with the new string instead of appending.